# Setting blender context for uv editing issue

Tags: python, uv

I'm trying to run this command, I crash after print 1, which I guess has something to do with setting another context but no idea how to bite it to get it to work... Any hints?

```
        print("Update graph")
        bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()
        for window in bpy.context.window_manager.windows:
            screen = window.screen
            for area in screen.areas:
                if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
                    #set context to 3dview
                    cont = bpy.context.copy()
                    cont['area'] = area
                    cont['region'] = area.regions[-1]
                    bpy.ops.view3d.view_selected(cont)
                    break

        if len(objects) > 0 and cont is not None:
            # Deselect all
            for obj in objects:
                if obj.type == 'MESH':
                    obj.select_set(state=False)

            #Select 1 by 1, and apply the uv system.
            for obj in objects:
                if obj.type == "MESH":
                    obj.select_set(state=True)
                    print("1",cont)
                    bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle(cont)
                    print("2",cont)
                    bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')
                    print("3",cont)
                    bpy.ops.uv.smart_project(cont)
                    print("4",cont)
                    bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle(cont)
                    obj.select_set(state=False)
```

TIA

I have missed some explanations.

This function is called by a persistent handler

```
@persistent
def load_handler(dummy):
    bpy.app.timers.register(actionQueue.runInternalFastTimer)

def register()
      bpy.app.handlers.load_post.append(load_handler)
```

Its done this way as I'm sending command to it from a threadX that is not blender thread. So the idea is to push job function ptr to a queue that then  gets called/executed by blender in its own correct thread.
However at that stage I have wrong context and I get this error >

```
RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle.poll() failed, context is incorrect
```

**EDIT** A more comprehensive example of the issue can be found here (second post) > https://devtalk.blender.org/t/creating-a-valid-context-for-uv-editing/15670

Comment: What is in the error log? Code is not full. What is `objects`? If this is `bpy.data.objects` and some objects are not in the context viewlayer, select_set will raise Error. `cont` is defined only in `if` statement, so if there's no 'VIEW_3D' area Error is also will be raised.

Comment: Hey, apology objects its bpy.context.view_layer.objects.selected, The function gets called by a ```bpy.app.timers.register(actionQueue.runInternalFastTimer)``` Which gets send there from another thread. Esentially I'm pushing a job from threadX to blender thread via timers. When the timmer run the function it has wrong context.

Comment: @AndreySokolov I've updated original question with more info. I'm sorry for lack of it from the start.

Comment: This is why it is generally recommended to avoid using bpy.ops as far as this is possible: Blender operators are very context-dependent, and it's pretty hard here to find out what is the exact problem with the context for `bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()`. I'd suggest trying to write the full context override instead of `bpy.context.copy()`, including exact `"window"`, `"screen"`, `"area"`, `"region"` and `"scene"`. But the problem also may be anywhere else: current mode, no active object, hidden objects... really too many cases to guess.

Comment: @AndreySokolov yes I try to avoid them. But I'm not sure how else can I perform this action. I just want to batch apply UV mapping to all selected objects. Any ideas? I tried doing full copy, but that seem to not work either :- (

Comment: Maybe after deselecting all objects some deselected non-mesh object remains active object, or there's no active object in the scene at all. Selecting objects this way doesn't make the last selected object active as if it would be done by user. Try to make one of the selected mesh objects active object for the context view layer. It can be done with `bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = ` some object

Comment: @AndreySokolov Super latte reply. Apology, I tried the active object, sadly did not help. I keep on having the wrong context and I have no idea how to generate/create/get the correct context :/ I tried now ignoring the entire set editabkle/etc and just called directly > bpy.ops.uv.smart_project() This is the error log > its interesting ! https://pastebin.com/VHiF89Mw

Comment: Well, in the first long-long line there is really no `active_object` key in the Context dictionary which is supposed to determine the context active object. It leads to the `AttributeError`, the active object remains unset in the Context which leads to the error in the `smart_project` operator's `@poll` method (which determines condition which allows to execute the Operator). You may try to somehow manually add `active_object` to the Context dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Running this script from the cli, I can unwrap an object in the background (no gui window).

I think the key point is setting the active object not just selecting it. I also create a uvmap layer if one doesn't exist and use `mode_set` rather that `editmode_toggle`.

```
import bpy

# Deselect all
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')

for obj in bpy.context.scene.objects:
    if obj.type == 'MESH':
        obj.select_set(state=True)
        bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
        bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')
        if len(obj.data.uv_layers) == 0:
            obj.data.uv_layers.new()
        bpy.ops.uv.smart_project()
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
        bpy.ops.wm.save_mainfile()
```

I saved it as uvproject.py and used the cli command

```
blender -b test.blend -P uvproject.py
```

Comment: Hey, I can see it working because its being send from correct thread/managed by blender. But it wont work with my example above... Here is forum post with more examplantion in post2 as to the issue > https://devtalk.blender.org/t/creating-a-valid-context-for-uv-editing/15670